# Ilink64 error: unresolved external - SendMessageW

Tags: c++builder

I have transferred my small project from the previous version Builder C++ to 10.1 Berlin and I got the unresolved external error. According to an advice, I have changed the TMessage to the TMessageBase.
The bellow mentioned code works as Win32 but doesn't work on Win64.

Error:

```
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external
'System::Messaging::TMessageManager::SendMessageW(System::TObject*, 
System::Messaging::TMessageBase*, bool)' referenced from 
C:\USERS\TOM\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\PROJECTS\PROJECT\WIN64\DEBUG\UNIT.O
```

Code:

```
TMessageManager *MessageManager;
TMessage__1 *Message;

Message = new TMessage__1("_FINISHED");
MessageManager = TMessageManager::DefaultManager;
MessageManager->SendMessage(this, Message, true);
```

Could anybody help me how to fix this bug? Thank you.
Tom

Comment: Was your initial Win32 project in UNICODE? Check if you are required to `#define UNICODE`  and related macros as you did in Win32. Also i think specifying strings in plain quotes ("_FINISHED") will declare them as normal ANSI strings and not as UNICODE strings. You might have to specify strings as `_T("_FINISHED")`. In short `SendMessageW` is a UNICODE version of `SendMessage` and expects all things UNICODE.

Comment: Note that you cannot use `TMessage__1` without specifying a template parameter, eg: `TMessage__1<String>`.  Which will then cause more linker errors, because `TMessage__1` is a C++ class for a Delphi Generic class `TMessage<T>`, and you can't use a Delphi generic class in C++ unless the project links to a Delphi-compiled unit/package that instantiates the Generic class so the implementation exists for the C++ linker to find.  There is no `TMessage<String>` used in the VCL, so you have to add a dummy `.pas` file that uses `TMessage<String>` to your C++ project to generate an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **classic** issue with the Win32 API in C/C++ environments.

`TMessageManager` does not have a `SendMessageW()` method.  It has a `SendMessage()` method instead.  And the Win32 API has its own [`SendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) function, with `#define` statements in the `winuser.h` header to map the generic `SendMessage` name to the Ansi (`SendMessageA`) or Unicode (`SendMessageW`) variant of that function:

```cpp
WINUSERAPI
LRESULT
WINAPI
SendMessageA(
    __in HWND hWnd,
    __in UINT Msg,
    __in WPARAM wParam,
    __in LPARAM lParam);
WINUSERAPI
LRESULT
WINAPI
SendMessageW(
    __in HWND hWnd,
    __in UINT Msg,
    __in WPARAM wParam,
    __in LPARAM lParam);
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SendMessage  SendMessageW
#else
#define SendMessage  SendMessageA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

`#define` statements are global in scope, they do not respect namespace boundaries, class boundaries, etc.  So this remapping affects **all** uses of the `SendMessage` name regardless of its context.  Microsoft has been asked many times over the years to fix this in the Win32 API for C++, where a simple fix (for all affected API functions) would look something like this:

```cpp
#if defined(UNICODE)
#define _MAP_WINNAME(n) n ## W
#else
#define _MAP_WINNAME(n) n ## A
#endif // UNICODE || _UNICODE

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
inline LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(
    __in HWND hWnd,
    __in UINT Msg,
    __in WPARAM wParam,
    __in LPARAM lParam)
{
    return _MAP_WINNAME(SendMessage)(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
#else
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SendMessage  SendMessageW
#else
#define SendMessage  SendMessageA
#endif // !UNICODE
#endif
```

Clean, simple, no ambiguity, respects classes/namespaces, etc etc etc.  But sadly Microsoft has not done this for its C++ users.

In any case, for your situation, the preprocessor is silently changing the declaration of `TMessageManager`'s `SendMessage()` method to `SendMessageW()` before the compiler sees it.  The preprocessor is also changing *your* code to call `MessageManager->SendMessageW(...)` instead of `MessageManager->SendMessage(...)`.  The compiler is perfectly happily to accept these changes and thus produces code references to `TMessageManager::SendMessageW()` in the compiled object files.

But the real name of `TMessageManager`'s method is still `SendMessage()` in the precompiled library that implements it.  The linker cannot find an implementation for `TMessageManager::SendMessageW()`, so it can't resolve the reference that the compiler produced, thus the error.

Embarcadero actually has a solution for this underlying Win32 API problem (which is a widely known problem in C++Builder for many years) - [`#pragma alias`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_alias).  Most VCL headers that are affected by this issue have suitable `#pragma alias` statements (with corresponding `{$HPPEMIT}` statements in their Pascal source code to generate these `#pragma` statements).  But Embarcadero has not applied this solution to `TMessageManager` yet.  I have filed a bug report in Quality Portal for it:

[[RSP-15041] System.Messaging.hpp is missing #pragma alias statements for TMessageManager::SendMessage()](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15041)

Until Embarcadero fixes it, you can apply the following fix to your own code directly:

```cpp
#if defined(_VCL_ALIAS_RECORDS)
#if !defined(UNICODE)
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageA$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageA$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBaseo"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBaseo"
#else
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBaseo"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBaseo"
#endif
#endif

TMessageManager *MessageManager;
TMessage__1 *Message;

Message = new TMessage__1("_FINISHED");
MessageManager = TMessageManager::DefaultManager;
MessageManager->SendMessage(this, Message, true);
```

In 10.0 Seattle (and probably earlier), the aliases are slightly different:

```cpp
#if defined(_VCL_ALIAS_RECORDS)
#if !defined(UNICODE)
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageA$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessage"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessage"
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageA$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessageo"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessageo"
#else
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessage"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessage"
#pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessageo"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp25System@Messaging@TMessageo"
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have added the pragma directives but I got the same error message again. Please, are the aliases right and where should they be placed?

Comment: @TomTom I do not have Berlin installed, but the aliases I showed are based on the exported names in Seattle. Maybe the signature of `TMessageManager.SendMessage()` changed in Berlin? You can tdump the implementing package and update the aliases if needed. You can put the pragmas anywhere you want as long as the preprocessor sees them.

Comment: Please, help me once more. Which package or file contains this link? I have already tried rtl bpl and dll and fmx but nothing of them works. I found #pragma alias "@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"
 but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @TomTom: The signature did change in Berlin (`TMessage*` -> `TMessageBase*`). The alias you show in the comment above is *NOT* fully plain ASCII, there are some non-ASCII characters in it. You can't see them above, but if you copy/paste the above alias into a (non-Notepad) text editor, you can see 4 `?` characters appear where they don't belong (`"@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessageW$qqrxp14System@TObjectp29System@M??essaging@TMessageBase"="@System@Messaging@TMessageManager@SendMessage$qqrxp14Syst??em@TObjectp29System@Messaging@TMessageBase"`). Aliases use ASCII characters only.

Comment: It was not a problem. The characters were added in this post only. It must another problem but I cannot find it. I have already tried many versions of the possible solution but without any success. It looks that the link is missing somewhere in the .a import library.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution. The problem is that the signature in Win64 is completely other than Win32. The problem is in the importing library "rtle.a" because just TMessageE instead of TMessageBaseE is mentioned there. Linker is looking for the signature with TMessage. It seems it is a set of the two bugs that are caused by "rtle.a" - SendMessage vs SendMessageW and TMessage vs TMessageBase. The library "rtle.lib" in Win32 is OK and it works.
The right code that works is here:

```
#if _WIN64
 #if defined(UNICODE)
  #pragma alias "_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager12SendMessageWEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseE"="_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager11SendMessageEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseE"
  #pragma alias "_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager12SendMessageWEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseEb"="_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager11SendMessageEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseEb"
 #else
  #pragma alias "_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager12SendMessageAEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseE"="_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager11SendMessageEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseE"
  #pragma alias "_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager12SendMessageAEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseEb"="_ZN6System9Messaging15TMessageManager11SendMessageEPNS_7TObjectEPNS0_12TMessageBaseEb"
 #endif
#endif
```

Thank all for help.